# zend_db adapter not in / zend_db_expr

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a call to a model which is just a standard class (not extending zend_db_table). I am doing a select and want to have the possibility of excluding a set of ids which which would be passed in as a variable.

I curently have the following:

```
public function getItemsBySection($section, $excluded_ids=null){
    //handle this as special case (although only case at this point)

    if(is_array($excluded_ids) and count($excluded_ids)>0){
        $x=1;
        foreach($excluded_ids as $key=>$value){
            if($x==1){
                $not_in=$value;
            }else{
                $not_in.=','.$value;
            }
            $x++;
        }
    }

    if($section=='feed_supplies'){
        $sql='select * from items where is_feed_supply=1';
        if($not_in){
            $sql.=' and id not in ('.$not_in.')';
        }
    }

    echo $sql . '<br/>';

    $results=$this->_db->fetchAll($sql);
```

but was wondering if there is a way to use Zend_Db_Expr or some other concstruct to handle the exclusion of certain items? I'm not error handling like if it is an integer etc...

I personally am not that big of a fan of the zend_db_select syntax but could be persuaded if it fixes things like this (want to see Doctrine2).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about using Zend_Db_Expr, but you don't need that first loop at all to build your $not_in value.

```
$not_in = implode( ',', $excluded_ids );
```

Comment: agreed -   i think i'd just written a foreach loop and it just came out way - certainly tidies it up

Answer (score 4):

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from('items')
       ->where('is_feed_supply = ?',1)
       ->where('id NOT IN (?)', $notInArray);
```

The $notInArray will be imploded automatically AFAIK (at least for ints). And then

```
$yourSQL = $select->__toString();
```

Zend_Db_Select rocks :D

And BTW: Try to stick to coding standarts

Comment: Except that Zend_Db_Select does not rock since you had to check $notInArray is not empty. Otherwise, you'll get a SQL syntax error... Great.